# Force String to given length in Haskell

Tags: haskell

so I want this function:

```
>formatLine :: (String, Int) -> String
>formatLine (a, b) = a ++ (rep (30 - length(a, b)) '.') ++ formatPence(b) ++ "\n"
```

and the rep function is as follows:

```
>rep :: Int -> Char -> String
>rep x n = concat["." | r <- [0..x]]
```

the idea being it would put the right number of dots to make the time of length 30.

And it's always making a line 50 long, no matter if I change 30.

I'm a real Haskell newbie, forgive me for the simple question, this has been annoying me for hours!

Comment: For an explanation of why `length` does what it does for pairs, see [The Not-a-Wat in Haskell](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=87re_yIQMDw).

Comment: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your intention with `length(a,b)` is to sum the length of `a` and the string representation of `b`. `length` doesn't work like that. Instead you should do something like

```
formatLine (a, b) = a ++ (rep (30 - length a - length (formatPence b)) '.') ++ formatPence b  ++ "\n"
```

Also -- your definition of `rep` is off. It should be

```
rep n x = [x | r <- [1..n]]
```

if your intention is to take an Integer and a Char and get a string of length n consisting of the character x repeated n times. Since in Haskell a string *is* a list of chars you don't need anything like `concat` -- a simple list comprehension will do. Furthermore, your `rep` itself seems a bit pointless in view of the Standard Prelude function `replicate`.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work for me :(. Couldn't match expected type [Char] with actual type Char

Comment: @CallumMcKinnon-Snell I didn't test it originally since I lacked an implementation of your `formatPence` function. When I looked at it more closely just now  I noticed that there was a problem with your `rep` function.